Разное количество запросов к серверу. Почему?
Вопрос к экспертам: Каждая ли команда от gspread отправляет запрос?
`gc = gs.service_account(filename="service_files/creds.json")
wks = gc.open_by_key("скрою на всякий")
article = []
price = []
batch_data = wks.worksheets()
for data in batch_data:
    article.extend(data.col_values(3))
    price.extend(data.col_values(4))
print(article)`

тут он не жалуется на 429, но так он жалуется на 429:
`gc = gs.service_account(filename="service_files/creds.json")
     article = []
     price = []
     for i in range(1,35):
         wks = gc.open_by_key("скрою на всякий").get_worksheet(i)
         article.extend(wks.col_values(3))
         price.extend(wks.col_values(4))
     print(article)`

как это работает?
В первом примере мы одним запросом получаем листы и с ними оперируем, так?
Но во втором примере мы открываем листы 35 раз, что меньше чем 60
А если col_values тоже запрос кидает, то почему тогда первый не летит?
